# How can I customize the mui circularprogress bar?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[image]

I want to customize it like the image above.
I want to give white for the margins and blue for everything else.

This is my source code.

```
 <CircularProgress
        variant="determinate"
        color={!action ? "primary" : "progress_second"}
        {...props}
        size="215px"
        thickness={3}
        variant="determinate"
        value={Math.round((props.value?.done / props.value?.total) * 100 || 0)}
        style={{
          transform: "rotate(440deg)",
        }}
      />
```

This is my circularprogress. 
[image]

please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Check this out it might help in your case. You can set whatever color you want to the spinner using sx prop:

https://smartcodehelper.com/2022/01/25/material-ui-circular-progress-customization-example/

```
<CircularProgress 
  variant="determinate" 
  size="10rem"
  {...props}
  sx={{color:"red"}} 
/>
```

or use predefined theme colors such as primary, secondary etc

```
 <CircularProgress 
      variant="determinate" 
      size="10rem"
      {...props}
      color="secondary" 
    />
```